# Is there a way to tell a Steam shortcut to open in big picture mode?

Tags: steam, pc

I have a monitor and a TV side by side. Sometimes I want to game from my couch and sometimes I want to sit and game at the computer.

When I'm gaming at my desktop I don't have the TV on. When Steam is in regular mode, it plays to my desktop, when it is in Big Picture mode, it plays on my TV.

I have Windows 10 and controller companion.

**Is there a way for me to set Steam via the shortcut to open in Big picture mode?**

That way I can have both a regular Steam shortcut and a big picture mode shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays Steam uses a different option. This command works for me:

```
start "Steam" /wait /b "steam://open/bigpicture"
```

Comment: What happens if you just do `start steam://open/bigpicture`? My understanding is that all steam browser protocol commands should start steam if it's not currently running: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol

Comment: True, that works just as well. 

Comment: Thanks for the update to this information.

Answer (score 9):

Yes there's a way, according to this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/2evzcu/steam_big_picture_mode_desktop_shortcut/) and this steam [forum discussion](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/bigpicture/discussions/2/882960163727915929/), there's a option to add to your shortcut.

> Create a shortcut to steam then in the properties edit the the target location and add -bigpicture at the end so it should be something like; "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" -bigpicture

Steam forum (changed < > to " " since it wouldn't render correctly here) :

> "your steam location"/steam.exe -bigpicture